# A* Pathfinding - Weird Bug in Multi-Floored Maps

Tags: java, algorithm, a-star

I'm attempting to create a game "dungeon" map generator in Java in the style of roguelike etc. games. I generate rooms randomly, and then connect them with corridors. I'm trying to use A* pathfinding in corridor creation. I currently am creating just one corridor between rooms in the indices 1 and 2, if there is more than one room.

For some reason, the corridor creation seems to fail when I try to generate more than 1 maps ("floors"). The amount of floors is specified as a command-line parameter. Thus far, when I've generated just one floor, everything works perfectly. My gut feeling says that there's something about the floors that messes up my algorithm.

I thought that maybe an outside view of the project could help. There is quite a lot of code, but I'd be very grateful if someone took the time to review it. I can provide more information if it's needed.

THE RESULTS

The result, when correct, should look like this:

```
Map 1

# wall
. floor
+ door
$ corridor

..............................
..............................
..............................
..............................
..............................
..............................
..............................
..............................
...........$$$$$$$$$$.........
...........$......##+#######..
.....######$......#........#..
.....#....#$......#........#..
.....#....#$......#........#..
.....#....#$......#........#..
.....#....#$......#........#..
.....#....#$......#........#..
.....#....#$......#........#..
.....##+###$......##########..
.......$$$$$..................
..............................
```

The buggy result looks like this (the corridor does not go door-to-door, it just ends in a random location):

```
...........$$$...#########....
...........$#+##.#.......#....
...........$#..#.#.......#....
...........$#..#.#.......+....
###+###....$#..#.#.......#....
#.....#....$#..#.#.......#....
#.....#....$#..#.#.......#....
#.....#....$#..#.#########....
#.....#....$####..............
#.....#....$..................
#.....#....$..................
#######....$..................
...........$..................
...........$..................
...........$..................
...........$..................
...........$..................
...........$..................
.......$$$$$..................
..............................
```

THE CODE

AStar.java:

```
/**
 * See https://www.raywenderlich.com/4946/introduction-to-a-pathfinding
 */
public class AStar {

    private List<AStarSquare> openList;
    private List<AStarSquare> closedList;

    private Exporter debugExporter;

    private static final Coords[] squareOffsetsToCheck = new Coords[] {
        new Coords(0, 1),
        new Coords(1, 0),
        new Coords(0, -1),
        new Coords(-1, 0)
    };

    public AStar() {
        openList = new ArrayList<>();
        closedList = new ArrayList<>();
        debugExporter = new Exporter();
    }

    public List<Coords> findPath(Coords start, Coords end, Map map) {

        List<Coords> path = new ArrayList<>(); // each square on the generated path

        AStarSquare currentSquare = new AStarSquare(start, null); // current square around which possible squares are evaluated - start point
        closedList.add(currentSquare); // add start point to closed list

        createUpdateOpenSquares(currentSquare, start, end, map); // create open squares for first iteration
        calculateScores(start, end, map); // calculate scores for first iteration

        int loopGuard = 0;

        // loop until break
        while(true) {
            if(openList.size() == 0) {
                break;
            }
            currentSquare = getLowestOpenSquare(); // get the square with the lowest score
            if(isAdjacentToDoor(currentSquare.getCoords(), end) /*|| currentSquare.getCoords().equalz(end) || loopGuard >= 1000*/) // end point reached or no possible next squares
                break;                                                          // - exclude last square (door)
            openList.remove(currentSquare);
            closedList.add(currentSquare);
            createUpdateOpenSquares(currentSquare, start, end, map); // create and/or update squares next to the current square
            calculateScores(start, end, map);
            map.setDebugCorridor(formulatePath(currentSquare));
            loopGuard++;
        }

        path = formulatePath(currentSquare);

        return path;
    }

    private void createUpdateOpenSquares(AStarSquare currentSquare, Coords start, Coords end, Map map) {

        for(Coords squareOffsetToCheck : squareOffsetsToCheck) {
            Coords coordsToCheck = currentSquare.getCoords().vectorAdd(squareOffsetToCheck); 
            if(map.isFloor(coordsToCheck) 
                    && !map.isInsideRoom(coordsToCheck)
                    && isWithinMap(map, coordsToCheck)
                    && !isClosed(coordsToCheck)) {
                AStarSquare openSquare = getOpen(coordsToCheck); 
                if(openSquare == null)
                    openList.add(new AStarSquare(coordsToCheck, currentSquare));
                else // is open
                    openSquare.setPrevious(currentSquare);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isClosed(Coords coords) {
        for(AStarSquare closed : closedList) {
            if(closed.getCoords().equalz(coords))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private AStarSquare getOpen(Coords coords) {
        for(AStarSquare open : openList) {
            if(open.getCoords().equalz(coords))
                return open;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean isWithinMap(Map map, Coords coords) {
        if(coords.getX() < 0 
                || coords.getY() < 0 
                || coords.getX() >= map.getW()
                || coords.getY() >= map.getH())
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    private boolean isAdjacentToDoor(Coords coords, Coords end) {
        for(Coords squareOffset : squareOffsetsToCheck) {
            Coords offsetSquare = coords.vectorAdd(squareOffset);
            if(offsetSquare.equalz(end))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void calculateScores(Coords start, Coords end, Map map) {
        for(AStarSquare square : openList) {
            square.calculateScores(map, start, end);
        }
    }

    private AStarSquare getLowestOpenSquare() {

        AStarSquare lowestScore = null;

        for(AStarSquare square : openList) {
            // if lowestScore not set or if square.f is lower than lowestScore.f, set square to lowestScore
            if(lowestScore == null || lowestScore.getF() > square.getF())
                lowestScore = square;
        }

        return lowestScore;
    }

    // exclude first square (door)
    private List<Coords> formulatePath(AStarSquare currentSquare) {
        List<Coords> path = new ArrayList<>();
        while(currentSquare.getPrevious() != null) {
            path.add(currentSquare.getCoords());
            currentSquare = currentSquare.getPrevious();
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

AStarSquare.java:

```
/**
 * See https://www.raywenderlich.com/4946/introduction-to-a-pathfinding
 */
public class AStarSquare {

    private Coords coords;
    private AStarSquare previous;

    private int g, h;
    private boolean calculated;

    public AStarSquare() {
        g = h = 0;
        calculated = false;
    }

    public AStarSquare(Coords coords) {
        this();
        this.coords = coords;
        previous = null;
    }

    public AStarSquare(Coords coords, AStarSquare previous) {
        this();
        this.coords = coords;
        this.previous = previous;
    }

    public void calculateScores(Map map, Coords start, Coords destination) {
        g = previous.getG() + 1; // g = distance from start point
        h = destination.getDistance(coords); // h = estimated (=shortest) distance from the current location to the destination
        calculated = true;
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class DungeonMapGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> argsList = Arrays.asList(args);

        if(!argsList.contains("-w") 
                || !argsList.contains("-h") 
                || !argsList.contains("-f")) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java -jar DungeonMapGenerator.jar -w [width] -h [height] -f [floors] -[export option]");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int width = 0, height = 0, floors = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if(args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-w"))
                width = tryParseInt(args, i + 1, 30);
            else if(args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-h"))
                height = tryParseInt(args, i + 1, 20);
            else if(args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-f"))
                floors = tryParseInt(args, i + 1, 1);
        }

        Generator mapGenerator = new Generator(width, height, floors);
        List<Map> maps = mapGenerator.generateMaps();

        Exporter mapExporter = new Exporter();

        if(argsList.contains("-c"))
            mapExporter.exportToConsole(maps);
        else
            System.out.println("No export option selected, quitting");
    }

    private static int tryParseInt(String[] args, int index, int deflt) {
        int res;
        if(index >= args.length) // index out of range
            res = deflt;
        try {
            res = Integer.parseInt(args[index], 10);
        } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
            res = deflt;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Generator.java

```
public class Generator {

    private static final int
        MIN_ROOMS = 1,
        MAX_ROOMS = 5,
        MIN_DIM = 3, // dim = min and max room dimensions
        MAX_DIM = 10;

    private AStar pathfinder;
    private Random random;

    private int mapWidth, mapHeight, floors;

    public Generator(int mapWidth, int mapHeight, int floors) {
        pathfinder = new AStar();
        random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        this.mapWidth = mapWidth;
        this.mapHeight = mapHeight;
        this.floors = floors;
    }

    public List<Map> generateMaps() {

        List<Map> mapList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < floors; i++) {
            Map map = new Map(i + 1, mapWidth, mapHeight, generateRooms(mapWidth, mapHeight), null);
            generateDoors(map, map.getRooms());
            debugFindPath(map);
            mapList.add(map);
        }

        return mapList;
    }

    private List<Room> generateRooms(int mapWidth, int mapHeight) {

        List<Room> roomList = new ArrayList<>();
        int nRooms = random.nextInt(5) + 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < nRooms; i++) {

            Room room = null;

            do {

                int w = 0, h = 0, x = 0, y = 0;

                w = getRandomDim();
                h = getRandomDim();
                x = random.nextInt(mapWidth - w);
                y = random.nextInt(mapHeight - h);

                room = new Room(x, y, w, h);

            } while(roomsOverlap(room, roomList));

            roomList.add(room);
        }

        return roomList;
    }

    private boolean roomsOverlap(Room room, List<Room> rooms) {

        for(Room listRoom : rooms) {
            if(room.overlapsWithRoom(listRoom))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private int getRandomDim() {
        return random.nextInt(MAX_DIM - MIN_DIM + 1) + MIN_DIM;
    }

    private void generateDoors(Map map, List<Room> roomList) {

        for(int i = 0; i < roomList.size(); i++) {

            Door door = new Door(roomList.get(i));

            do {
                door.setSide(getRandomCardinal());
                door.setDistNW(getRandomDistNW(roomList.get(i), door.getSide()));
            } while(!validateDoor(map, door));

            roomList.get(i).setDoors(Arrays.asList(new Door[] { door }));

            map.getDoors().add(door);
        }
    }

    private Cardinal getRandomCardinal() {
        int cardinalInt = random.nextInt(4);
        Cardinal cardinal;
        switch(cardinalInt) {
        case 1:
            cardinal = Cardinal.EAST;
            break;
        case 2:
            cardinal = Cardinal.SOUTH;
            break;
        case 3:
            cardinal = Cardinal.WEST;
        case 0:
        default:
            cardinal = Cardinal.NORTH;
            break;
        }
        return cardinal;
    }

    private int getRandomDistNW(Room room, Cardinal cardinal) {
        int distNW = 0;
        if(cardinal == Cardinal.NORTH || cardinal == Cardinal.SOUTH)
            distNW = random.nextInt(room.getW() - 2) + 1; // exclude corners
        else if(cardinal == Cardinal.EAST || cardinal == Cardinal.WEST)
            distNW = random.nextInt(room.getH() - 2) + 1; // exclude corners
        return distNW;
    }

    private boolean validateDoor(Map map, Door door) {

        Coords doorCoordsOnMap = door.getCoordsOnMap(); 

        if(door.getSide() == Cardinal.NORTH 
                && (door.getParent().getTop() == 0 
                    // check if adjacent to another room
                    || map.isWall(new Coords(doorCoordsOnMap.getX(), doorCoordsOnMap.getY() - 1))))
            return false;
        else if(door.getSide() == Cardinal.EAST 
                && (door.getParent().getRight() == mapWidth - 1 
                    // check if adjacent to another room
                    || map.isWall(new Coords(doorCoordsOnMap.getX() + 1, doorCoordsOnMap.getY()))))
            return false;
        else if(door.getSide() == Cardinal.SOUTH 
                && (door.getParent().getBottom() == mapHeight - 1
                    // check if adjacent to another room
                    || map.isWall(new Coords(doorCoordsOnMap.getX(), doorCoordsOnMap.getY() + 1))))
            return false;
        else if(door.getSide() == Cardinal.WEST 
                && (door.getParent().getLeft() == 0
                    // check if adjacent to another room
                    || map.isWall(new Coords(doorCoordsOnMap.getX() - 1, doorCoordsOnMap.getY()))))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    private void debugFindPath(Map map) {
        if(map.getRooms().size() == 1)
            return;
        map.setDebugCorridor(pathfinder.findPath(
                map.getRooms().get(0).getDoors().get(0).getCoordsOnMap(), 
                map.getRooms().get(1).getDoors().get(0).getCoordsOnMap(), 
                map
        )); 
    }
}
```

Room.java

```
public class Room {

    private Coords topLeft;
    private int w, h;
    private List<Door> doors;

    public Room(int topLeftX, int topLeftY, int w, int h) {
        topLeft = new Coords(topLeftX, topLeftY);
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        doors = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean overlapsWithRoom(Room otherRoom) {
        return !(otherRoom.getLeft() > this.getRight()
                || otherRoom.getRight() < this.getLeft()
                || otherRoom.getTop() > this.getBottom()
                || otherRoom.getBottom() < this.getTop());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Room ~ top: " + getTop() + " right: " + getRight() 
            + " bottom: " + getBottom() + " left: " + getLeft()
            + " width: " + w + " height: " + h;
    }

    public boolean isWall(Coords coords) { /*** TESTAA!!! ***/
        if(
                // x is either left or right, y is between top and bottom 
                ((coords.getX() == topLeft.getX() || coords.getX() == topLeft.getX() + w) 
                    && coords.getY() >= topLeft.getY() && coords.getY() < topLeft.getY() + h + 1)
                ||
                // y is either top or bottom, x is between left and right
                ((coords.getY() == topLeft.getY() || coords.getY() == topLeft.getY() + h)
                    && coords.getX() >= topLeft.getX() && coords.getX() < topLeft.getX() + w)
                )
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Door.java

(Cardinal is a simple enum containing NORTH, EAST, SOUTH and WEST)

```
public class Door {

    private Room parent;
    private Cardinal side;

    private int distNW = 0;

    public Door(Room parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.side = null;
    }

    public Door(Room parent, Cardinal side) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.side = side;
    }

    public Coords getCoordsOnMap() {
        Coords coords = null;
        if(side == Cardinal.NORTH)
            coords = new Coords(parent.getLeft() + distNW, parent.getTop());
        else if(side == Cardinal.EAST)
            coords = new Coords(parent.getRight(), parent.getTop() + distNW);
        else if(side == Cardinal.SOUTH)
            coords = new Coords(parent.getLeft() + distNW, parent.getBottom());
        else if(side == Cardinal.WEST)
            coords = new Coords(parent.getLeft(), parent.getTop() + distNW);
        return coords;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "seems to fail" mean?

Comment: @Blorgbeard The corridor does not go from one door to another, it ends in a wrong place on the map. The reason seems to be related to multiple floors.

Comment: You seem to have left out the map generation, which is probably one of the more important parts of this.  Are you sure you use a new instance of `AStar` for each floor?  What debugging have you done already?  Try using print statements or a debugger to see where it's having issues

Comment: My bad, I added Generator.java to the question. I have, for example, printed the map on each iteration of `AStar.findPath()`, but there are hundreds of iterations when processing just one map, so I didn't gain much insight to the bug. I've also pointed out (with the 'X' character) the closed list squares on each iteration.

Comment: Try resetting your `AStar` object before you generate each floor (at the start of the for loop should work).  From your example images it looks like it's pathfinding to the old door location and not the new one

Comment: @phflack That seemed to do it, the old map was interfering for some weird reason. Thanks!

Comment: Added an answer with two different ways to fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AStar`, your A* pathfinding algorithm adds to its opened and closed lists before returning the chosen path

When pathfinding with different start/end destinations or a different map, those lists will need to be reset

The issue is that you're reusing the `AStar` object for each path you're trying to find, causing conflicts with old searches

To fix it, use a new `AStar` object for every path you search, or add a method to clear the old data

Answer (score 0):

I removed this line from the Generator constructor:

```
public Generator(int mapWidth, int mapHeight, int floors) {
    // pathfinder = new AStar(); // REMOVED THIS LINE
    ...
}
```

And I added the following line to the Generator.generateMaps method:

```
public List<Map> generateMaps() {

    List<Map> mapList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < floors; i++) {
        pathfinder = new AStar(); // ADDED THIS LINE
        Map map = new Map(i + 1, mapWidth, mapHeight, generateRooms(mapWidth, mapHeight), null);
        generateDoors(map, map.getRooms());
        debugFindPath(map);
        mapList.add(map);
    }

    return mapList;
}
```

And now everything seems to work.

Another option is to add the following lines to `AStar.findPath()`:

```
public List<Coords> findPath(Coords start, Coords end, Map map) {

    openList = new ArrayList<>();
    closedList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note that if you plan on pathfinding more than once a floor, you will need to reset it in between path searches, not just in between floor generations